# How to offer website visitors to install Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to offer my clients to install Chrome if they came in to the website using IE (any version).

It better be some kind of a native dropdown bar (like IE has).

Are there a "minimum coding" solutions?

Website uses jQuery and PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless this is for some specific application or intranet-like page, **please** don't do this.  Leave your users alone, let them use whatever they want.  It is up to you to make your page work for as many of them as possible.

Comment: Why would you like to do that? Your visitors should have the choice which browser they want to use. It's client software, that's not your department. The times when sites where optimised for Browser x at screen resolution y are fortunately over.

Comment: I would simply display a box somewhere on the page that doesn't distract the user too much, similar to what google does on it's landing page.

Comment: @KevinB chances are they see Google's home page a lot more than yours, so why aren't they using Chrome already? Well either it's up to them and they don't want to, or they have no control over what is installed on their machine

Comment: 2Brad, 2Jay: You are definitely wrong. IE is a pile of #$?% that does not render my jQuery animations correct way, it does not support simple things like round borders (without workarounds). As result - the end-user gets an ugly content VERY SLOW. I'm doing the right thing - forcing users to get any other browser (this takes at most 3 minutes) and brings up a lot more better browsing experience.

Comment: Microsoft had a LOT of time to bring IE to a better level.

Comment: @tomfumb - Why does that matter at all? I don't care if they see it at google, i'll show it again on my site. It's more exposure. If they can't upgrade, that's their problem, not mine. I don't support IE6 unless the specific application needs it. If the user is using IE6 on one of those sites/applications that don't support IE6, they will simply get degraded support with a suggestive box on the side suggesting them to upgrade. What is the harm? If they can't upgrade, they can't upgrade. the box isn't preventing them from doing anything. How many of the IE6 users are using the default MSN home?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a pretty minimal solution using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome">Download Chrome!</a>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks! This works stable on all IEs (6-9). Just dropped it to a 100px height container with yellow background and changed text to: Sorry, your browser is outdated. Please install any newer browser: <a>Chome</a>, <a>Firefox</a>, <a>Opera</a> ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) and it's easy to [setup a website](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started), just include the following code in the head of the layout:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

You can also [prompt the user to install it](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Detecting-Google-Chrome-Frame-and-P).

Comment: Just followed your instructions "prompt the user to install it". This brings up a huge annoying window covering whole website. =))) People will run away. =)

Comment: We use this for our IE6 users. So far we haven't had any feedback, good or bad, and our IE6 traffic has not changed. I wouldn't suggest using this for users of IE7 and IE8 since IE7 and IE8 aren't very troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this jquery functionality](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

Test if "msie" is "true" and proceed accordingly.

Comment: "The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery."